# While loop prints out the same result, Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I've tried to put this password generator into a while loop, so I could create a wordlist, which I'm going to use in an assignment of mine.

So far, the program prints out the same result constantly when run. The code for my program is:

```
from random import shuffle
data = open('randomwords.txt', 'r').read().split()
shuffle(data)

# Creates password from Gadsby text file
password = ''
for x in data[:3]:
    password += x

while(True):
    print password.replace('o', '0')
```

Does anyone know how to change this code, so it prints out different passwords, instead of printing out the same password constantly.

Comment: would you not need to shuffle the data after each print?

Comment: `password` is only constructed **once**. In the loop, you only replace `o` with `0`. So nothing changes anymore...

Comment: I understand that, how would I go about putting the whole thing into a while loop, everything I've tried doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
from random import shuffle
with open('randomwords.txt', 'r') as data:
    data = data.read().split()
    while(True):
        shuffle(data)
        password = ''
        for x in data[:3]:
            password += x
        print password.replace('o', '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

A more pythonic way of doing this would be this.

```
from random import sample
with open('randomwords.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().split()
    while(True):
        print ''.join(sample(data, 3)).replace('o', '0')
```